# Plot Dataframe by DataTime Grouping by Month, Year, Day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

How can I make a Plot counting the elements that are in a specific Time Group. I have a dataframe like this

```
Incident_Number Submit_Date Description
001 05/04/2017 12:00:45 Problem1
002 05/05/2017 13:00:00 Problem2
003 05/05/2017 14:00:00 Problem3
004 07/05/2017 19:00:00 Problem4
005 07/06/2017 08:00:00 Problem5
```

and how could be possible to make a line plot that show me the total Incidents by month, date, weekday, or year. I tried grouping by, but this take many lines, first extracting the month, year, and date and then transforming again in datetime to visualize. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with converting `Submit_Date` into a timedate (if it is not a timedate yet) and making it the index:

```
df['Submit_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Submit_Date'])
df.set_index('Submit_Date', inplace = True)
```

Now you can resample your data at any frequency and plot it. For example, resample by 1 month (get monthly counts):

```
df.resample('1M').count()['Description'].plot()
```

Comment: Excellent it works, thanks I didn't know about this function (resample)